# How can I setup Postfix to deliver a mail to multiple local users as a copy?

Tags: linux, email, postfix, fedora

Is it possible for Postfix (on FC7) to recieve an email at a@example.com and automatically forward a copy to b@example.com and c@example.com and d@example.com? I can't use .forward files because this is a virtual server with virtual domains, there are no /home/user directorys for email accounts.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a line to `/etc/aliases` to that effect:

```
a: b c d
```

The `@example.com` in your case is assumed, as I understand. Don't forget to run `newaliases`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `/etc/postfix/virtual` is what you need? Take a look at the manpage [virtual(5)](http://www.postfix.org/virtual.5.html).

Comment: Well the server is hosted by GoDaddy and runs their Simple Control Panel.. I tried adding the aliases to /etc/postfix/turbopanel/virtual-alias but it doesn't seem to allow multiple lines of the same originating address.

Comment: I don't have a similar postfix installation by hand to test this on. But if I read the manpage correctly, the format is comma-separated addresses on a single line. For example: `a@example.com   b@example.com, c@example.com, d@example.com`

Answer (score 1):

The 'transport_maps' option in the postfix main.cf is the one that should be used.

The transport_maps points to /etc/postfix/transport.db file that contains the entries.

You can add the transport entries in /etc/postfix/transport file
and run the 'postmap' command which will generate the transport.db file.